# Decimal Values get converted into NULL when trying to insert into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert the result of the following query

```
SELECT T.City_Name, T.[Day of the Year],
AVG(T.Average_Temp) OVER (PARTITION BY T.City_Name ORDER BY T.[Day of the Year] 
ROWS BETWEEN 3 Preceding AND 1 following) as Rolling_Avg_Temp
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT City_Name, DATEPART(DY, Date_Local) AS 'Day of the Year', 
AVG(Average_Temp) AS Average_Temp
FROM Updated_Temperature_Data
WHERE
City_Name IN ('Tucson')
GROUP BY City_Name, DATEPART(DY,Date_Local)) T;
```

[image: output for the query is decimal numbers:]

When I try to insert these values into a column called `rolling_avg` (decimal(6,2)) in other table, all the values show as NULL.

[image: result after insertion]

Command to create a column to store values:

```
alter table table_name add rolling_avg decimal(6,2);
```

Command to insert query into column:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(rolling_avg) SELECT 
AVG(T.Average_Temp) OVER (PARTITION BY T.City_Name ORDER BY T.[Day of the Year] 
ROWS BETWEEN 3 Preceding AND 1 following) as Rolling_Avg_Temp
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT City_Name, DATEPART(DY, Date_Local) AS 'Day of the Year', 
AVG(Average_Temp) AS Average_Temp
FROM Updated_Temperature_Data
WHERE
City_Name IN ( 'Tucson')
GROUP BY City_Name, DATEPART(DY,Date_Local)) T;
```

Comment: you need an UPDATE not an INSERT

Comment: Please only select relevant tags